# How to check 'Output bit depth' of the libx264 library in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, video-encoding, x264, libx264

According to the [x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide), the `crf` scale depends on whether x264 is 8-bit or 10-bit. Supposedly `x264 --help` shows the `Output bit depth`. But on Windows `ffmpeg -h full` doesn't say anything about `Output bit depth` and the `crf` scale option is described as `from -1 to FLT_MAX`. How can I check if my ffmpeg is using 8-bit or 10-bit version of the libx264 library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run `ffmpeg -h encoder=libx264` and look for values of supported pixel formats.

For bit-depth=8 of libx264 it will be something like:

> Supported pixel formats: yuv420p yuvj420p yuv422p yuvj422p yuv444p yuvj444p nv12 nv16

And for bit-depth=10 of libx264 it will be something like:

> Supported pixel formats: yuv420p10le yuv422p10le yuv444p10le nv20le